# Collaborative map editing using local openstreetmap server

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping

I tried to make a collaborative web-map solution. that is allowing multiple users to edit map features and enter data collaboratively.
I read that [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) give this solution.

I've installed a local osm server using [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/) tutorial.
Now I can see a map canvas on a web page.

**But**, How can I manage map data. I mean:

- Defining features categories.
- Defining users as editors.
- Assigning privileges to users according to geographic area.

Is there any other open source solution, more easy to set up and meet my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Your "switch2osm" is a rendering server - it takes existing OSM vector data and turns it into tiles that can be viewed on a web client.

If you want to edit the existing OSM vector data, you've got a lot more work to do. You also have to sort out licensing issues if you are going to re-use the OSM data.

You probably need to install much more backend than your "switch2osm" rendering server. A full backend is known as ["the rails port"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rails_port). It is [on github](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website).

You might also want to [choose an editor](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Comparison_of_editors) and install it with appropriate connection to your database. For example, if you want a developmental version of iD (which is included in the rails port in a stable version), start with https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD/blob/master/README.md and work from there.

For the legal side, read and understand http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright and find a lawyer if any of it is not clear to you.

Comment: Thank you @BradHards, Is there any other open source solution, more easy to set up and meet my requirement?

Comment: Well that depends on the complexity of the data that your users need to enter. If it's somehow similar to OSM, I would recommend to give the railsport a try, just because it enables you to recycle all of the OSM ecosystem (editors, processors, renderers, ...).  
Maybe it's also an alternative to spend some money to [a consultant](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services) to do this things for you.

Comment: lio: I think I answered your (original) question. I don't think it would be too hard to set up (perhaps a different question after you've tried), just that it is additional work after setting up a rendering server. Another option would be something like a WFS-T client / server (e.g. see http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html)